# R - split strings in a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, split

I have never worked with lists of dataframes in R before. Maybe it's not even complicated, but I can't help myself right now.

So I got a list of dataframes

```
df1 <- data.frame(v5 = c(0.5,0.6,0.7,0.96),v6 = c("Tiny|Marsian|Worker", "Tiny|Human|Student", "Tiny|Goblin|Soldier", "Tiny|Horse|Guardian"))
df2 <- data.frame(v5 = c(0.56,0.32,0.55),v6 = c("Tiny|Human|Worker", "Tiny|Marsian|Student", "Tiny|Goblin|Soldier"))

ldf <- list(df1,df2)
```

Each dataframe contains 6 columns (in this case only 2) and the number of rows differs in each df.
Column V6 contains three different information, each seperated by a "pipe" |
What I now need to do is to split these information by the "pipe" and make three individual columns out of it. As I would get it for a single df out of

```
library(stringr)
split = str_split_fixed(string = df1$v6, pattern = "\\|", n = 3)
```

And after that I'd like to append the information which now ends up in column 2 back to the individual dataframes of ldf

In the end I want my dataframes to look like this

```
    df1 <- data.frame(v5 = c(0.5,0.6,0.7,0.96),
v6 = c("Tiny|Marsian|Worker", "Tiny|Human|Student", "Tiny|Goblin|Soldier", "Tiny|Horse|Guardian"), 
v7=c("Marsian","Human","Goblin","Horse"))
    df2 <- data.frame(v5 = c(0.56,0.32,0.55),
v6 = c("Tiny|Human|Worker", "Tiny|Marsian|Student", "Tiny|Goblin|Soldier", 
v7 = c("Human", "Marsian", "Goblin")))
```

How do I achieve this? I already tried several thing with

```
x <- lapply(ldf, `[`, 6)
```

but have issues when using splitfuctions!
Please help me

Comment: Thx, included the library 'stringr' into the code

Comment: How did a tiny horse with a guardian appeared? :/

Comment: fixed, the tiny horse guardian issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr` and `purrr`:

```
library('dplyr')
library('purrr')
ldf2 <- map(ldf, mutate, v7 = str_split_fixed(string = v6, pattern = "\\|", n = 3)[, 2])

ldf2

[[1]]
   v5                  v6      v7
1 0.5 Tiny|Marsian|Worker Marsian
2 0.6  Tiny|Human|Student   Human
3 0.7 Tiny|Goblin|Soldier  Goblin

[[2]]
    v5                   v6      v7
1 0.56    Tiny|Human|Worker   Human
2 0.32 Tiny|Marsian|Student Marsian
3 0.55  Tiny|Goblin|Soldier  Goblin
```

`mutate()` adds new column to `data.frame` based on string splitting, and`map()` is applying this `mutate()` to every element of `ldf`.

**EDIT:**

If you want three different columns, you shoul use:

```
ldf2 <- map(ldf, separate, col = 'v6', into = c('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'), sep = '\\|')
```

Answer (score 0):

With `lapply`,`tidy::separate` and `do.call` functions you could do:

```
combinedDF = do.call(rbind,lapply(ldf,function(x) { 

x %>% 
tidyr::separate(v6,c("v70","v7","v72"), sep = "\\|", remove=FALSE) %>%
dplyr::select(-c(v70,v72))

}))
```

Without `lapply/rbind` (thanks to @Sotos)

```
bind_rows(ldf) %>% 
tidyr::separate(v6,c("v70","v7","v72"), sep = "\\|", remove=FALSE) %>% 
select(-c(v70, v72))


combinedDF
#    v5                   v6      v7
#1 0.50  Tiny|Marsian|Worker Marsian
#2 0.60   Tiny|Human|Student   Human
#3 0.70  Tiny|Goblin|Soldier  Goblin
#4 0.56    Tiny|Human|Worker   Human
#5 0.32 Tiny|Marsian|Student Marsian
#6 0.55  Tiny|Goblin|Soldier  Goblin
```

Comment: If you intend to make the final result one big data frame (which it seems not to be what OP wants), then you should use `bind_rows`, i.e., `bind_rows(ldf) %>% separate(v6,c("col1","col2","col3"), sep = "\\|", remove=FALSE) %>% select(-c(col1, col3))`. I also added another select statement to drop unwanted columns